# Fetching data from Facebook SDK to iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

How can I fetch data from facebook to my app. I need fetch name, age, gender, profile picture and other picture. I must put these data to labels and UIView, just like this: self.labelName.text = userID.name...

I use this code but is no working with Facebook SDK 4.0 and higher:

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
NSLog(@"%@", user);
self.profilePicture.profileID = user.id;
self.labelName.text = user.name;
self.gender.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];}
```

And what if user doesn't have all info, ex. gender or age?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook integration needs following steps

1) Go to developer.facebook.com and register your app.
2) get the api key for your application.
3) Drag drop SDK in your application bundle.
4) Request for specific information to user.

You can find more information along with demo on www.developer.facebook.com

[Login with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4)

[FBGraph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4)

[Facebook integration demo](https://github.com/NikhilDevgire/loginWithFacebook)